# eventBus get double @Subscribe

Tags: java, android

On Service I post Event  and into my `activity` I get two this same events  i try did this :

```
@Subscribe(sticky = true, threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)
public synchronized void onEvent(EventAddNoteAndRealize event) {

    if (eventAddNoteAndRealize == null) {
        this.eventAddNoteAndRealize = event;
        getRealizeAndNote(event);
    } else if (event != null && event != eventAddNoteAndRealize) {
        this.eventAddNoteAndRealize = event;
        getRealizeAndNote(event);
    }   
}
```

but always i have `eventAddNoteAndRealize`  `null`

In Service I post this evet just like this :

```
EventBus.getDefault().post(new EventAddNoteAndRealize(noteAndRealizeDAOs));
```

Comment: add the code from where you are trigerring the event

Comment: add a log and print the value of noteAndRealizeDAOs , just before sending the Event

Comment: @Thunder I added but I see that I send only one time this event

Comment: if its printing once , that means your service is just sending the event once.

Comment: @Thunder but I have two times onNext on this same objects

Comment: in this case you need to check are you trigerring events correctly